# Cam Sling Modification

Tags: climbing, diy, camming-devices

How do you modify Cam slings with a straw as described [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/how-do-i-correctly-clean-remove-tri-cams) for easier removal?

Comment: Taking the initiative I see. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mr. Wizard has the jist of it but I thought I might add in what I have done. I cut a plastic straw (I use gas station straws that are pretty thick but McDonald's would work as well) to go from just below the head to about an inch past the first loop. then I wrapped the straw to the webbing with athletic tape. I then used a sharpie to color the tape the same color as the webbing so it's still easy to identify.

I then took some more tape and wrapped it around the webbing just below the pin and then wrapped it over the pin and through the trough between the rails.

The entire intention is to be able to place the pro one handed. The stiffer head makes it very easy to flick it one way or the other to change between active and passive placement. If you can place it one handed then you can spend more time getting it just right. Also, the additional wrapping on the head adds a bit of spring when placed as a cam which makes it easier to "activate" without yanking on it or yanking as hard, thus easier to remove.

The major draw back to this is the rope will apply more upward pressure and can possible remove the placement so most people who do this connect a sling as well, to give the line more freedom of movement before affecting the placement.

These are not pictures of mine but they look pretty close. The main differences being I colored my mid sections and I didn't come up as far with the tape, I only went right past the pin.

[image: Modification]

Answer (score 2):

From [*Simple Mechanics: Why Tricams Still Rule* (PDF)](http://www.camp-usa.com/product-highlights/forum/simple-mechanics-why-tricams-still-rule/Simple%20Mechanics%20-%20Why%20Tricams%20Still%20Rule.pdf):

> #### Stiffen the Sling
>
> One way to help make Tricams easier to place and remove is to stiffen
>   the upper part the slings.  Over the course of the Tricam’s history,
>   we have seen many solutions for this, but one remains superior. It is
>   important to consider that while stiffening can help, it can also
>   reduce the lexibility of the sling and render the unit ineffective by
>   taking away its ability to adapt to various directions of pull. The
>   solution: use a material with some rigidity that also bends easily
>   when needed. Like a soda straw. As with spit balls, McDonalds straws
>   are the best. They are thick and well built. Cut a length that its
>   perfectly in the upper sling loop and hold it in place with a thin
>   layer of athletic tape. It’s cheap and it works.